# Eth address can't be used for mining

Tags: mining, addresses, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I'm trying to mine from my linux, but when I run the following command:

```
ethminer -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=4@ERroYPhmyUFMgPNRJEDNBlaBlaBla@Optional
```

I get error

```
JSON_PARSE_ERROR: The JSON-Object is not JSON-Valid:  Invalid Ethereum address length
```

However when doing it with a hex address:

```
ethminer -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=10@0x54e8efbd6138011efe9b028e489f6a0bc650e451@OptionalRigName
```

I don't get an error, however the 0xEtc is a dummy value.

How can I find out the hex value of my ETC wallet address? Or am I approaching this wrongly?

I followed instructions in https://ethereumpool.co/how/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address is contained, by default, in the name of the account file storing the private key corresponding to that address.

If you do not have an Ethereum client, download [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases) (since it's the most used right now and run the commands:

```
mkdir myMiningDir
geth --datadir myMiningDir account new
# Enter and reenter the passphrase
cd keystore
ls 
# You should see your next account as a file with the name <account address>--<timestamp>
```

Make sure you write down/remember the password for that account otherwise you won't be able to spend any ether from its balance.

Comment: Alright, so thats assuming I have created an account and not just installed my wallet right? I got my wallet on a separate windows machine - all I did was open the exe and use that as wallet. I'm probably missing something. Where can I found this account file?

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Alright! this is looking good. So I can use geth to manage my account, send money to other wallets and etc?

Comment: Yes, you can launch the geth IPC client to interact with the client more easily and make your transactions from there.

Answer (score 3):

Add `0x` in front of your address.